# The memory layout of a multithreaded process

Tags: linux, memory, memory-layout

Well I know that there is a heap that is common for all threads which grows upwards and we have stacks for each of the threads which grow downwards (Is it really so, the stack growing downwards or is it just a simplistic view?). I even read somewhere that stack can be a part of the heap space.
And how are these stacks placed? One above the other? What happens if the stack at the top overflows and attempts to write the stack below it? Is it really like this?
A detailed view please.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it with a short Python "program" in the interactive interpreter:

```
import threading
import time
def d(): time.sleep(120)
t = [threading.Thread(target=d) for _ in range(250)]
for i in t: i.start()
```

Then I pressed `^Z` and looked at the appropriate `/proc/.../maps` file for this process.

It showed me

```
00048000-00049000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00049000-00848000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:28625]
00848000-00849000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00849000-01048000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:28624]
01048000-01049000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
01049000-01848000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:28623]
01848000-01849000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
01849000-02048000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:28622]
...
47700000-47701000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
47701000-47f00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:28483]
47f00000-47f01000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
47f01000-48700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:28482]
...
bd777000-bd778000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
bd778000-bdf77000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:28638]
bdf77000-bdf78000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
bdf78000-be777000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:28639]
be777000-be778000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
be778000-bef77000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:28640]
bef77000-bef78000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
bef78000-bf777000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:28641]
bf85c000-bf87d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

which shows what I already suspected: the stacks are allocated with a relative distance which is (hopefully) large enough.

The stacks have a relative distance of 8 MiB (this is the default value; it is possible to set it otherwise), and one page at the top is protected in order to detect a stack overflow.

The one at the bottom is the "main" stack; it can - in this example - grow until the next one is reached.